# How to model a many self-referential relationship with many parents?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, database-design, activerecord

I want to model out the following in the easiest way:

A skill has many dependent skills.

Each skill should exist on their own, and a skill may have other skills that are prerequisite skills.

For example:

```
Skill: Front-End Development Has Dependent Skills -> [HTML, CSS, SCSS]
Skill: Web-Design Has Dependent Skills -> [HTML, CSS]
Skill: HTML
```

I'd like to be able to do:

```
@front_end_development.dependent_skills ##or a more semantic mapping
```

I'd probably like to walk up the tree but I can't think of the best name to do so. Perhaps I'd like to reference through HTML that Web-Design depends upon it.

---

Does it make sense to make this self-referential or is the fact that this is hurting my brain a code smell and beg that something else is ideal? It all comes down to a skill depending on other skills.

Would it be better to model this using mongo?

Comment: I love semantics; proper use of semantics makes modeling easier to grasp. I try not to be too abstract as it breaks down the understanding and I rather use my brain power for more important things. Anyway, I think the [ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) may solve my needs with abstract methods. Thoughts?

Comment: I don't know that ancestry will help. Ancestry supposes a tree structure - you need multiple parents which is more of a directed-graph. A tree can be modelled with a simple "parent_id", but with multiple parents you are more likely to need a join table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iterating through the tree (more like a directed graph actually) each time you need to retrieve all dependencies for a skill, you might just iterate through the implied dependencies when adding a new dependency to a particular skill and save these to a table called 'Dependency' which maps a skill to a dependency and vice versa. For example (the relations could be better worded):

```
class Skill
    has_many :dependers, class_name: 'Dependency', foreign_key: :dependee_id
    has_many :dependees, class_name: 'Dependency', foreign_key: :depender_id

    has_many :dependencies, through: :dependees
    has_many :depending, through: :dependers

    def add_dependency(skill)
        recurse_dependencies(skill)
    end

    def recurse_dependencies(skill)
        # perform this check to avoid circular and duplicate dependencies
        if !depender_ids.include?(skill.id) && !dependee_ids.include?(skill.id)
            dependee_ids << skill.id
        end

        skill.dependencies.each do |dependency|
            recurse_dependencies(dependency)
        end
    end
end

class Dependency
    belongs_to :dependee
    belongs_to :depender
end
```

You should then be able to do things like:

```
@front_end_development.dependencies
@front_end_development.depending
@front_end_development.add_dependency(@html)
```