# How to do a self referential model in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I recently posted this question: [How to model a many self-referential relationship with many parents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532187/how-to-model-a-many-self-referential-relationship-with-many-parents)

I got an adequate answer, but I was told that I could model this better using Mongo/Mongoid. I always wanted to attempt using a different database paradigm so maybe this will be a good start.

Is it true that this would be easier to model using Mongo? If so, could you help lay it out for me?

I basically have two options right? 1 is to create an array through a document that references Skill id's through it? E.g, Skill.prerequisites = [Skill1, Skill2, Skill3]. Something that works with that structure right?

Otherwise it may be that I need to run something logical on that association so I'd have to create a separate model. This is where I get confused. Given I may need to create a separate model, does that exist as a document or an embedded document? What are my limitations w/ each strategy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so let's go with your skill approach. Here's how I'd model it in Mongoid:

```
class Skill
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :prereqruisite_skill_ids, type: Array, default: []

  def prereqruisite_skills
    Skill.any_of(:_id => prereqruisite_skill_ids).all
  end

  def add_prereqruisite!(skill)
    self.prereqruisite_skill_ids << skill
    safely.save!
  end
end
```

With Mongo, this is the only way I would do it.

With ActiveRecord, you could:

```
class Skill < AR::Base
  has_many :skill_prereqruisites
  has_many :prerequisites, through: skill_prereqruisites, class_name: "Skill"
end

class SkillPrereqruisite < AR::Base
  belongs_to :skill_one, foreign_key: "skill_one_id"
  belongs_to :skill_two, foreign_key: "skill_two_id"
end
```

Comment: Interesting. So in the case of the Mongo one, the prerequisite wouldn't be able to actually know it's a prerequisite? In Mongo's case I could never put extra logic on that association? It would only serve as an array at the most? E.g, skill.is_a_prerequisite_of and possibly more.

Comment: For Mongo, if you want to know it's a prerequisite, you'll need to also store that info in the prerequisite --- like a "subsequent_skills" or something. At that point, it begins to look like a tree, right? So check out https://github.com/benedikt/mongoid-tree

Comment: Sorry, pardon my ignorance because I'm trying to digest these various concepts; but how come in the other thread they labeled it more of a directed graph? Initially I thought it was a tree structure but after being told it's more of a directed graph I can see that, because any one skill can be associated with another. What would you say is a better representation of this data? Would you say go for mongo or the good ol' relational?

Comment: @daniel -- well, it's probably the fact that you can have have parents, that's probably why a tree won't work, now that I think about it. I would go relational, unless you're already using mongo.