# Rails. Association of the same model with many parents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I stuck with this. I have a model `Position` and I need to set an association where a position can be a `compounded position` (has related positions) and an `ingredient position` (has parent(s) position) at the same time.

So I created a table `related_positions` with `:copmound_id` and `:ingredient_id`.

To be clear what I need as an output:

**related_positions**

compound_id | ingredient_id|

pos_1 | pos_2

pos_1 | pos_3

pos_1 | pos_4

pos_5 | pos_2

pos_5 | pos_6

pos_5 | pos_7

---

pos_1.ingredients = [pos_2, pos_3, pos_4]

pos_5.ingredients = [pos_2, pos_6, pos_7]

pos_2.compounds = [pos_1, pos_5]

---

It might be kind of `self join` but with multiple parents

UPDATE:

I found this [How to model a many self-referential relationship with many parents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532187/how-to-model-a-many-self-referential-relationship-with-many-parents). Which is very close. But I still can't get it work

Comment: SO! what is your question?

Comment: How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to that post http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2007/10/30/self-referential-has-many-through I've got what I needed.

So, if someone has a similar case here is my solution:

```
class Position < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :parents, class_name: 'RelatedPosition', foreign_key: 'ingredient_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :children, class_name: 'RelatedPosition', foreign_key: 'compound_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :compounds, through: :parents
  has_many :ingredients, through: :children
end

class RelatedPosition < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ingredient, class_name: 'Position'
  belongs_to :compound, class_name: 'Position'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

From the description shared association can be something mentioned below:

```
class Position

 has_many :related_positions, class_name: "RelatedPosition", foreign_key: "ingredient_id", :source => :relate_position
 has_many :compounds, class_name: "RelatedPosition", foreign_key: "compound_id", :source => :compound_position
end


class RelatedPosition
 belongs_to :relate_position, class_name: "Position"
 belongs_to :compound_position, class_name: "Position"
end
```

Comment: I f you change related_positions to ingredients this will mirror the syntax poster noted/desired

Comment: What are the associations in the RelatedPosition model?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you want to do is a self-reference
Something like this might work

```
class Position
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Position', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Position'
end
```

Comment: It must be possible to set many parents for a position. Look at my example

Comment: I see now, but you said "has parent position", in the singular, so I assumed it was just one

Comment: sorry. my bad )))